# vb.net progress bar is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'minimum' and 'maximum'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, loops, progress-bar, max

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If ProgressBar2.Value = 100 Then
        ProgressBar2.Value = ProgressBar2.Maximum()
        MsgBox("Posting Completed!")
        ProgressBar2.Enabled = False
    Else
        Do
            ProgressBar2.Value += 5
        Loop
    End If


End Sub
```

It's been 3 hour I'm working to figure what the problem is, but until now i still can't find a solution for this, no error until i run it, it gives me this error

**Value of '105' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'minimum' and 'maximum'.
Parameter name: Value**

I already set my

```
ProgressBar2.Minimum = 0
ProgressBar2.Maximum = 100
```

Please help me out :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something is wrong in your code above.

The loop

```
    Do
        ProgressBar2.Value += 5
    Loop
```

will never stop and when it reaches 100 it will increment past the maximum value.
No, the test at the entry of the method will not be executed while you are inside this loop

You should increment just one time and then exit the loop and wait for the next Timer tick to increment again

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If ProgressBar2.Value + 5 >= ProgressBar2.Maximum Then
        ProgressBar2.Value = ProgressBar2.Maximum
        MsgBox("Posting Completed!")
        Timer1.Stop()
    Else
        ProgressBar2.Value += 5
    End If
End Sub
```

Also, when you reach the Maximum you should simply stop the Timer1 not disable the ProgressBar2

Comment: And THIS is the problem, nice catch!

Answer (score 0):

Because you're increasing the value from 100 to 105, then it fails in the If statement because you're not checking to see if it's greater or equal `>=`.

Also, you can get rid of the loop as it has no exit.